# TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String) ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, xmlhttprequest

So I have a controller that accepts a JSON as payload

```
def create
     @tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))
    if @tournoi.save
      redirect_to root_url
        flash[:success] = "Your tournament bracket has been validated!"
```

the json is from a js diagram that's editable, I am saving the JSON with XMLHttpRquest and formData :

```
 function save() {
      var tojs = myDiagram.model.toJSON();
      var json = JSON.stringify(tojs);

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("payload", json);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("post", "http://localhost:3000/malesingle", true);
  request.send(formData);
                    }
```

The JSON is successfully inserted into my controller, I get redirected to a TypeError landing page on my create method from my tournois controller, I know my payload is nill before I save it, I don't know why  the way I declared `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))` isn't guaranteeing the conversion from nill to payload..

Comment: can you put brake point with byebug or pry before save to check value of@tournoi?

Comment: @Nezir never used pry or byebug dont really know how it works i'll look into it

Comment: Why not just send the whole request as JSON? This just seems like a very wonky solution to a simple problem.

Comment: its very simple if you are using rails 5.2 it is default just need to write before line  tournoi.save byebug and refresh page it will stop on that line. than in console write tournoi and it will show you a content  .. but its good to read about using it will be very useful for you in future

Comment: @max well i'm using the knowledge i know to handle json as payload, can you enlighten me a bit on send the request as JSON

Answer (score 0):

you did a wrong way to submit payload json to rails backend. So params is not json, it's string of json
You can try to remove this

```
var json = JSON.stringify(tojs);
```

line from code, and add tojs to formdata directly

```
formData.append("payload", tojs);
```

Comment: i still get a TypeError no implicit conversion of nil on   `@tournoi = Tournoi.new(payload: JSON.parse(params[:payload]))`